# IntelliJ loading image files as text files

Tags: intellij-idea

I had some Pngs that were working fine but when I put open them in IntelliJ it is trying to load them as a text file and makes it impossible to open the image even not in IntelliJ.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the **File name patterns** for the **Text** file type in the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types | **Recognized File Types** settings:

[image]